# Method arguments not applicable but they are correct

Tags: java, generics, methods, arguments

edit: not sure if this is a correct fix but for some reason adding extends Comparable gets rid of the errors

I keep getting this same error. Why?

The error I receive is:

> The method maxHeapify(T[], int) in the type HeapSort is not applicable for the arguments (T[], int)

Here's my code:

```
public class HeapSort {
    private static int parent(int i)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0)
        {
            return((i-1)/2);
        }
        else
        {
            return(i/2);
        }
    }

    private static int leftChild(int i)
    {
        return(2*i + 1);
    }

    private static int rightChild(int i)
    {
        return(2*i + 2);
    }

    private static <T> void buildMaxHeap(T[] array)
    {
        int heapSize = array.length;

        for(int i = (heapSize/2 - 1); i >= 0; i--)
        {
            maxHeapify(array, i);
        }
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void maxHeapify(T[] array, int i)
    {
        int L = leftChild(i);
        int R = rightChild(i);
        int Largest = (int) array[0];
        T temp;

        if(L <= array.length && array[R].compareTo(array[i]) > 0)
        {
            Largest = L;
        }
        else
        {
            Largest = i;
        }

        if(R <= array.length && array[R].compareTo(array[Largest]) > 0)
        {
            Largest = R;
        }

        if(Largest != i)
        {
            Swap(array[i], array[Largest]);
            maxHeapify(array, Largest);
        }
    }

    public static <T> void heapSort(T[] array)
    {
        buildMaxHeap(array);
        int heapSize = array.length;

        for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Swap(array[0], array[i]);
            heapSize = heapSize-1;
            maxHeapify(array, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is because this line defines T differently

```
private static <T extends Comparable<T>> void maxHeapify(T[] array, int i)
```

to this

```
private static <T> void buildMaxHeap(T[] array)
```

and this

```
public static <T> void heapSort(T[] array)
```

Its

```
<T>
```

vs

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

because buildMaxHeap and heapSort both call maxHeapify so you get a generics type mismatch

If you convert all the types to

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

Then this will fix that error

You will also have another error when you fix this

```
int Largest = (int) array[0];
```

because your array doesn't contain int's, it contains your generic type objects

Comment: i literally figured that out and as soon as i put my edit in your response showed up lol. but thanks. however, after fixing that, i didnt get the int casting error you were talking about, i know they arent ints but it had an error without the casting so i left it at that for now. when i change the largest variable to a T, i get errors because of L and R being ints and i cant compare them with the generic types

Comment: edit: not sure why i had it as Largest = array[0], it just needs to be the index and not the actual object. all errors fixed!